# Iteration using feature selection

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

[image]I have a point shapefile that includes meteorological data. I want to select and export some feature classes from that based on data observation date. This criteria is one of the fields in the original data but because of existing many rows, about 1 million records!, I must use iterate feature selection in model builder in ArcGIS.

I connect that iterator to Select tool to export selected records to my workspace in a Geodatabase. I use the inline in addressing to my outputs but unfortunately every exported feature class replaces the before one! So finally I just have a one feature class including of the last selected records.

What can I do to solve this issue?

[image: Modelbuilder]

Comment: It sounds like you may want to use the append tool rather than overwrite your results

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE, can you edit the question and include a screen shot of the model?  It sounds like your in-line variable substitution for the output feature class name is not changing per Select export.

Comment: show a screen shot of your model...It sounds like an issue with inline substitution variable naming. Your model may be giving the same name to each feature after processing.

Comment: You could also try: 1-Select by Attributes (select all dates you are interested in) and then 2-Split By Attributes with date field as split field. No need for Iterations and modelbuilder

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Tristan Forward  How can I use append tool?